# How to use gettext placeholders?

Tags: localization, internationalization, translation, gettext, vala

I'm not a programmer, but I want to help translating a project written in vala (http://live.gnome.org/Vala/Tutorial) using gettext. I encountered a problem when I had to rearrange parts of a sentence using placeholders.

Example:

```
public void show_retrieving_similars() {
    if(hint != ViewWrapper.Hint.SIMILAR || lm.media_info.media == null)
        return;

    errorBox.show_icon = false;
    errorBox.setWarning("<span weight=\"bold\" size=\"larger\">" + _("Loading similar songs") + "</span>\n\n" + _("BeatBox is loading songs similar to") + " <b>" + lm.media_info.media.title.replace("&", "&amp;") + "</b> by <b>" + lm.media_info.media.artist.replace("&", "&amp;") + "</b> " + _("..."), null);
    errorBox.show();
    list.hide();
    albumView.hide();
    similarsFetched = false;
}
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: You should probably report this as a bug to the project you are translating.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used vala and I haven't tested this, it looks like you need to replace

```
errorBox.setWarning("<span weight=\"bold\" size=\"larger\">" + _("Loading similar songs") + "</span>\n\n" + _("BeatBox is loading songs similar to") + " <b>" + lm.media_info.media.title.replace("&", "&amp;") + "</b> by <b>" + lm.media_info.media.artist.replace("&", "&amp;") + "</b> " + _("..."), null);
```

with

```
string title = lm.media_info.media.title.replace("&", "&amp;");
string artist = lm.media_info.media.artist.replace("&", "&amp;");
errorBox.setWarning(@"<span weight=\"bold\" size=\"larger\">Loading similar songs</span>\n\n BeatBox is loading songs similar to<b> $title </b>by<b> $artist </b>...", null);
```